# How to handle value errors during datatype conversion?

Tags: python, pandas

I have ~ 4000 datasets which I'm preparing for a concatenation. Among others I make sure, that the columns of each dataset has the same data format.I have a variable 'measuredHeight' which in some datasets has the datatype 'object' and some strings in it.

When I then try to reformat the variable to a float-type I get a value error:
`ValueError: could not convert string to float: '[5.084,4.645,4.632,4.481,4.204]': Error while type casting for column 'measuredHeight'`

This is the line of code, which causes the value error:

```
subset = df[relevantFields]
subset = subset.astype({'gml_id': 'str', 'Gemeindeschluessel': 'str', 'measuredHeight':'float', 'geometry':'geometry'})
```

How can I handle those errors as, for example, by setting values causing those value error to a float like np.nan?

Comment: `pd.to_numeric(df['col'], errors='coerce')`

Answer (score 1):

You could use [pd.to_numeric()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) to coerce the non-numeric values to np.nan

```
subset = df[relevantFields].copy()
subset['measuredHeight'] = pd.to_numeric(subset['measuredHeight'], errors='coerce')
subset = subset.astype({'gml_id': 'str', 'Gemeindeschluessel': 'str', 'geometry':'geometry'})
```

Comment: It doesn't throw an error anymore but it triggers the 'A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. '- warning.

Comment: add `.copy()` at the end of the first part to make a deep copy

Comment: I corrected with `subset.loc[:, 'measuredHeight] = `

Answer (score 0):

To handle the `measuredHeight` column, you could use the [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def convert_to_float(val):
    try:
        # Try converting directly to float
        return float(val)
    except ValueError:
        # If ValueError, check if it's a string representing a list
        if isinstance(val, str) and val.startswith('[') and val.endswith(']'):
            return np.nan  # or perform other operations as needed
        else:
            # If not convertible, return NaN
            return np.nan

# Applying the function to the 'measuredHeight' column
df['measuredHeight'] = df['measuredHeight'].apply(convert_to_float)
```